# Constraints on combinations of type parameters when using generics

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a declaration file for a library (chart.js). A new chart is constructed as follows:

```
let chart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'line', data: ..., options: ... })
```

where the types of data and options fields are dependent on the type field

In trying to model this, I thought to model the type of the object as a union type. This allows me to specify which objects can be passed to the constructor (using string literal types for the type field)

However, the data and options fields are accessible as properties from the class after construction and since I can't use the types of the fields of the passed in object I was thinking of using generics instead.

The problem I'm having now is that I'd need a different type parameter for each of the fields (type, data and options) but the types of data and options are determined by the type of the type field (a string literal), not just any combination is possible. Is there a way to only allow specific combinations of type parameters instead of all combinations? for example

```
let lineChart = new Chart<'line', LineChartData, LineChartOptions> // OK
let barChart = new Chart<'bar', BarChartData, BarChartOptions> // OK
let chart = new Chart<'line', BarChartData, LineChartOptions> // ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then you can do this:

```
interface ChartType<Data, Options> {
    type: "line" | "bar";
    data: Data[],
    options: Options[];
}

interface LineType extends ChartType<string, string> {
    type: "line";
}

interface BarType extends ChartType<number, number> {
    type: "bar";
}

class Chart<Data, Options> {
    constructor(ctx: any, type: LineType | BarType) { ... }
}

new Chart("ctx", { type: "line", data: [""], options: [] }); // ok
new Chart("ctx", { type: "bar", data: [98], options: [9] }); // ok
new Chart("ctx", { type: "line", data: [""], options: [3] }); // error
new Chart("ctx", { type: "ha?", data: [], options: [3] }); // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ChartType%3CData%2C%20Options%3E%20%7B%0A%09type%3A%20%22line%22%20%7C%20%22bar%22%3B%0A%09data%3A%20Data%5B%5D%2C%0A%09options%3A%20Options%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20LineType%20extends%20ChartType%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%20%7B%0A%09type%3A%20%22line%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20BarType%20extends%20ChartType%3Cnumber%2C%20number%3E%20%7B%0A%09type%3A%20%22bar%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Chart%3CData%2C%20Options%3E%20%7B%0A%09constructor(ctx%3A%20any%2C%20type%3A%20LineType%20%7C%20BarType)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20Chart(%22ctx%22%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22line%22%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%22%22%5D%2C%20options%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0Anew%20Chart(%22ctx%22%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22bar%22%2C%20data%3A%20%5B98%5D%2C%20options%3A%20%5B9%5D%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0Anew%20Chart(%22ctx%22%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22line%22%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%22%22%5D%2C%20options%3A%20%5B3%5D%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error))

Just replace my `string` and `number` with your data/options types.